# How to add / remove attribute when click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add/remove attribute when click?

This is what I tried so far.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).attr("title", "selected").siblings().removeAttr("title", "selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <button title="selected" class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When click button, add attribute "selected" and others remove attribute "selected".

This is DEMO,
https://jsfiddle.net/a8egp275/3/

How do I need to fix it? please help.

Comment: The `.removeAttr()` hasn't second parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the `.btn` elements are not siblings, hence `siblings()` returns nothing.

To fix this you can use `closest()` to get the nearest common ancestor, then `find()` the `.btn` elements, excluding the one which was clicked. Also note that `removeAttr()` only requires a single argument; the attribute name to be removed. Try this:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var $btn = $(this).attr("title", "selected");
  $(this).closest('ul').find('.btn').not($btn).removeAttr('title');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <button title="selected" class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your code and text are inconsistent with each other.   I personally wouldn't recommend the "clear all `.btn`" method because there may be others in different parts of the DOM.

Comment: @Alnitak you're correct - I changed my mind on my approach while writing the example and forgot to update the description :) I've put it back to how it originally was.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the title attribute from all dom with .btn class and then add the title to the selected element

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.btn[title ="selected"').removeAttr("title")
  $(this).attr("title", "selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <button title="selected" class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the attribute you just specify the name of the attribute
so you need to do as follows:

```
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        $('.btn').removeAttr("title");
        $(this).attr("title", "selected");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the current selected with an attribute selector

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('[title=selected]').removeAttr("title");
  $(this).attr("title", "selected");
});
```

```css
[title=selected] { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <button title="selected" class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn">click</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {

  //remove the selected attr from all btns
  $('.btn[title]').removeAttr('title');

  //add the title attr to the current btn
    $(this).attr('title', 'selected');

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a8egp275/42/

Note: this code will alwasy have one button selected, if you want this to behave as checkbox rather than radio button, you will need to do something like this:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {

    //get the attr title and check later if it exist
    var attr = $(this).attr('title');

  //remove the selected attr from all btns
  $('.btn[title]').removeAttr('title');

  //add the attr only if it didnt exist before
  if(typeof attr === typeof undefined || attr === false){
        $(this).attr('title', 'selected');
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a8egp275/45/

Answer (score -1):

your event handler is okay. But take a look in the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).
It states, that the removeAttr() function only takes the attribute name as a parameter.
Also afaik you have to make seperated statements for the add and remove, because the attr() function does not return the jQuery object.

TLDR:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).attr("title", "selected");
  $(this).siblings().removeAttr("title");
});
```

Also you need to change your HTML structure if you want to use the siblings() function :)

Comment: While this is true, it's not the problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are right, overlooked the first problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still has the same problem as the OP

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan third error found, in the html structure, the buttons are not siblings